# Is there any direct relation among first, third, fourth order moments?

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

Suppose that $X$ is a real-valued random variable, with $EX^4=1$ and $EX\leq0$. Find an explicit constant $c<1$ such that $EX^3<c$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ E(X_+) + E(X_-) = E(|X|) \le E(X^4)^{1/4} \le 1 $$
$$ E(X_+) \le E(X_-) $$
Therefore
$$ E(X_+) \le 1/2 $$
Apply Hoelder $E(UV) \le E(U^3)^{1/3} E(V^{3/2})^{2/3}$ with $U = X_+^{1/3}$, $V = X_+^{8/3}$:
$$ E(X_+^3) \le E(X_+)^{1/3} E(X_+^4)^{2/3} \le (1/2)^{1/3} $$
$$ E(X_-^3) \ge 0 $$
$$ E(X^3) = E(X_+^3) - E(X_-^3) \le (1/2)^{1/3} $$

Comment: How did you get $E(X_+)=E(X_-)\leq1/2$? $EX\leq0$ tells us that $E(X_+)\leq E(X_-)$.

Comment: Sorry about that.